# In PLSQL, what query determines whether a literal represents a view or a table?

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

I'm using a restricted querying tool. is there something that just returns one row, returning a boolean say whether a certain object is a view or a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the data dictionary

```
SELECT object_type
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE owner = <<owner of object>>
   AND object_name = <<name of object>>
```

will return you the `object_type` of all the objects that have a particular name that you have access to.  Normally, there will just be one row returned but occasionally there will be two.  A materialized view, for example, will have a table and a materialized view that share the same name.  A package and a package body will also have the same name.

Comment: neither any of the views nor any of the tables im currently querying are listed in all_objects....im sure thats just a matter of circumstances on this server though.

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - That doesn't make sense.  Unless someone explicitly did something very unusual like creating an `ALL_OBJECTS` view in the local schema, `ALL_OBJECTS` will show every object that you have access to.  If you can query it, it will appear in `ALL_OBJECTS`.  Can you give an example of an object that you can query (including exactly how you query it) and the query against `ALL_OBJECTS`?  Is it possible that you are querying synonyms (potentially owned by `PUBLIC`) rather than tables or views? Or perhaps you're not specifying the object name in upper case?